# Detectar width do Scrollbar

Tags: javascript

Para deixar bem estruturado uma pagina que terá o scrollbar desabilitado quando um determinado botão for clicado, penso em definir um padding adicional ao body com js, para compensar o scroll ocultado. Andei lendo por ai que muitos navegadores já possuem um width padrão de 17px, mas que outros tem especificações diferentes. O que preciso é de uma solução para detectar o width do scrollbar nativo documento, pegar esse valor e adicionar ao body.

`$('body').css('padding-right', WidthDoScrollbar);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Obter a largura do *scroll*

Através dessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382516/getting-scroll-bar-width-using-javascript) vi que é possível criar uma `div` escondida, outra `div` dentro dela com *scroll* e através da diferença das duas saber qual é a largura do *scroll* utilizado pelo navegador.

Esse é o código:

```js
function getScrollbarWidth() {
    var outer = document.createElement("div");
    outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
    outer.style.width = "100px";
    outer.style.msOverflowStyle = "scrollbar"; // needed for WinJS apps

    document.body.appendChild(outer);

    var widthNoScroll = outer.offsetWidth;
    // force scrollbars
    outer.style.overflow = "scroll";

    // add innerdiv
    var inner = document.createElement("div");
    inner.style.width = "100%";
    outer.appendChild(inner);        

    var widthWithScroll = inner.offsetWidth;

    // remove divs
    outer.parentNode.removeChild(outer);

    return widthNoScroll - widthWithScroll;
}

console.log(getScrollbarWidth());
```

Comment: estou utilizando a última versão do firefox. 60.0.1, no console está dando esse erro: `TypeError: document.body is null`

Comment: Sua tag *`<script>`* está no final da `tag` body?, esse erro pode estar sendo ocasionado porque o script está sendo executado antes de carregar o HTML completo.

Comment: Wow. Que detalhe! Agora funcionou. Thx.